# rpush gem disable rails log output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification

I am using rpush gem to send notification to IOS and Android.  Every thing works. However the rpush gem create log in log/production.log every few seconds. Is there a way to disable the log from rpush gem?

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but overwriting the Logging methods should work. Place the following in an initializer, like rpush.rb or similar.

```
module Rpush
  class Logger
    def info(msg, inline = false)
    end

    def error(msg, inline = false)
    end

    def warn(msg, inline = false)
    end
  end
end
```